# Bash regex matching not working in 4.1

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Upgraded to Bash4 and found that it is not matching regexes:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release

$ [[ "20110228" =~ "^[0-9]{8}$" ]] && echo matches
```

But Bash 3.0 is:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.00.16(1)-release

$ [[ "20110228" =~ "^[0-9]{8}$" ]] && echo matches
matches
```

Why might this be? Have I not installed it correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes/218217#218217) on SO. Since you are using 3.00 version of bash 3, it might regard your problem. Shortly, starting from 3.2 version, quoting the string argument to the `[[` command's `=~` operator forces string matching, so the correct pattern for bash 4 should be:

```
$ [[ "20110228" =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]] && echo matches
matches
```